# How do I find out and stop server Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian

I'm currently running a rails app on a remote Debian linux box and need to stop the rails server. Not sure which rails server it is. How do I find out which rails server it is and how to kill it?

Comment: do you know on which port your app is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ps aux | grep rails`
run this in command line then use
`pkill -9 rails` to kill all the process(rails).

Answer (score 0):

You need to find Rails process ID and kill that process. Use the following code to get the list of rails processes:

```
ps -ef | grep script/rails
```

Then, you can kill them by using this:

```
kill -9 <rails_process_id>
```